# Choco Sat Formulation

Tags: constraint-programming, sat, choco

I am trying to model a SAT formula using Choco 4.0.1. I read the [docs](http://choco-solver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/2_modelling.html#sat-constraints) , I am trying to understand from the [javadoc](http://www.choco-solver.org/apidocs/org/chocosolver/solver/Model.html), but unfortunately I am failing so far. This is my first time working on these type of problems and also choco. So, I may be asking something very obvious.

I need to add a number of constraints to the model like (each var is a BoolVar):

```
x <-> (a and -b)
```

I am trying to use ifOnlyIf method in Model, but I don't know how to negate a variable, or use and. Could someone provide me (ideally) some sample code or any ideas on how to model these types of constraints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the `Choco 4.0.1` [online manual](http://choco-solver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/2_modelling.html#sat-constraints), it should be something like this:

```
SatFactory.addClauses(LogOp.ifOnlyIf(x, LogOp.and(a, LogOp.nor(b))), model);
// with static import of LogOp
SatFactory.addClauses(ifOnlyIf(x, and(a, nor(b))), model);
```

However, the manual seems to be outdated.
Like suggested in the comment, I arrived at:

```
import static org.chocosolver.solver.constraints.nary.cnf.LogOp.and;
import static org.chocosolver.solver.constraints.nary.cnf.LogOp.ifOnlyIf;
import static org.chocosolver.solver.constraints.nary.cnf.LogOp.nor;

import org.chocosolver.solver.Model;
import org.chocosolver.solver.variables.BoolVar;

public class AkChocoSatDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // 1. Create a Model
        Model model = new Model("my first problem");

        // 2. Create variables
        BoolVar x = model.boolVar("X");
        BoolVar a = model.boolVar("A");
        BoolVar b = model.boolVar("B");

        // 3. Post constraints
        // LogOp omitted due to import static ...LogOp.*
        model.addClauses(ifOnlyIf(x, and(a, nor(b))));

        // 4. Solve the problem
        model.getSolver().solve();

        // 5. Print the solution
        System.out.println(x); // X = 1
        System.out.println(a); // A = 1
        System.out.println(b); // B = 0
    }
}
```

I have used `nor()` with single parameter as `not()` to negate an input.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the problem is, when I use SatFactory as in the sample, I can not reach the methods. I was wondering if I am doing something wrong. I would appreciate if you let me know if you try and it works.

Comment: Actually, I modified it a little bit and it seems to be working.

model.addClauses(LogOp.ifOnlyIf(x, LogOp.and(a, LogOp.nor(b))));